# Webpack + Typescript + Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, webpack

I need to use `$(#id).modal(...)` method from bootstrap in my typescript code to show a modal dialog programmatically. I have downloaded bootstrap via `npm install bootstrap --save` and added typings by executing `tsd install bootstrap --save`. Then I tried to include it in my app via `import bootstrap = require("bootstrap")`

But when I try to build my app in node.js command prompt by executing `webpack`, I get an error: `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bootstrap'.` I have then searched all over the google, tried using `bootstrap-webpack` without success (more specifically I couldn't get it configured, it was still throwing errors), but I didn't find anything which would make the bootstrap available in typescript.

I need only access to javascript part of bootstrap, in fact that single function is all I need. Is there any simple way how to make this configuration work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bootstrap

That happens if TypeScript cannot find `module "bootstrap"`, which should be there considering you have [this file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts) see code: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts#L119-L120

Make sure the file `bootstrap.d.ts` is *included in your `tsconfig.json`* file.

Comment: Duh, dumb `tsconfig.json`, always forgetting about it. The moment I could remember to add my own files I forget to add the library.. Thanks for making note of that!